# Hide/show button and link alternatively ? KnockOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I been working on this to hide/show which some simple variations .

**Stage1:**
I have a Link(Comment) initially when i click on that i need display a textarea with button at right botton of the textarea and here link button go to hidden state.

**Stage2:**
Later when i click on button(POST) the textarea as well as button should disappear and Link should be visible

**The stuff i tried so far :**

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: showBox">Comment</a>

<input type="textarea" data-bind="visible: show"/>
<input type='button' data-bind="visible: show"  value="show"/>
```

**KnockOutjs:**

```
var viewModel = function()
{
    self = this;
    self.show =  ko.observable(false);
    self.showBox = function(){
    self.show(true); 
     };
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Initially when i click on comment i am displaying textbox and button , but i am unable to hide link(comment) . Likely when i click button textarea and button should hide and comment link should appear .

Ps:i'm ameautur in knockout Help me . Thnak you

Regards

Comment: add a new function called hideBox which sets self.show(false). Set this as the click binding handler for the textarea button. add visible binding to the anchor tag like "visible: !show()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add the visible attribute to your link. Only show it when the show() is false!

```
 
<a href="#" data-bind="click: showBox, visible: show() === false">Comment</a>
```

Comment: One way its working fine . when we click link textarea & button displaying but other way when i click button i have to show link again . Any further clarity let me know

Comment: on your update button function on the way back, just set self.show(false); thats sit, simples! :-)

Comment: oops in fiddle its working fine but i am getting error i.e showBox undefined ? visible: show() === false ? . undefined exception coming . Do i need to create models ?

Comment: Since the fiddle is a working, need to establish the difference in what you are actually doing in your own code and the example.

Comment: same mate . just a copy paste from fiddle . sadly not working . any things i need to keep in mind while moving from fiddle . ty mate

Comment: Send me your html file and js code were its not working, you can get my email address from my profile!

Comment: now issue is sorted in place show() i done like $data.show() so onn .. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can alternate the view state like this.

```
self.showBox = function(){
   self.show(!self.show()); 
};
```

Comment: hard luck . Its not working . its working like a toggle but i dont require that . link & button should hide/show like when i click on link button with textarea should appear with comment link should hide itself . later when i click on button comment comment link should show and button & textarea should hide . any clarity let me know